# Facebook is not letting me add additional e-mail addresses to my account

Tags: facebook, account-management

I have nine e-mail addresses (including the primary) attached to my Facebook account. I've tried to add two more (one @outlook and one @yahoo), but I'm having trouble. When I click on the link in the confirmation e-mail, it takes me to the General Account Settings screen. There's nowhere to enter the confirmation code either. If I navigate back to the settings, the option "Resend confirmation email" is there, but clicking it sends me back to the same cycle.

Is there a limit to the number of e-mail address associated with an account? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Most likely there is a limit.

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a limit to the number of email addresses one can add. From a security perspective, in my opinion it looks like multiple users using the same Facebook account. There isn't anywhere in the help section that lists the hard limit though.

Consider choosing only the accounts you consider checking the *most* for Facebook updates.